# Android - 403 Forbidden on Form Submission

Tags: php, android, wampserver

I have created a User Registration Activity, that displays a form and on Submission sends the data  via HTTP Post to a URL that hosts a insert.php file. The host is currently my desktop and has a WAMP Server Running.

When I run the app through virtual emulator the data gets submitted correctly and I can verify it by checking the MySQL Database.

When I debug the app on my android phone, then the connection succeeds but the data is not submitted. I get a `403 Forbidden`  in a HTML Layout being returned by php script. when I check the Android Logs

Any leads as to what might be wrong?

insert.php snippet

```
$host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="user_db";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $uname,$pwd, $db);

$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, password, email, mobile)
    VALUES ('$name', '$password', '$email', '$mobile')";

print(json_encode($flag));
```

Comment: Is this WAMPServer you are running or XAMPP or one of the other WAMP stacks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's WAMP Server

Comment: I tried sending a explicit query to 127.0.0.1/insert.php with data and it works.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 means **this device** so on your phone it means **your phone** so that wont work as the web site is not on your phone.

Comment: Are you getting anywhere?

Comment: It is very impolite to just **Eat and Run** If an answer solved your problem **Accept the answer**. Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) If the problem still exists comment on the answer and ask for more assistance.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry man, currently I am not on my home network so I am unable to test it. I will surely accept the answer or post  additional issues if any once I run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Apache saying you have not allowed access to this site from the IP address that your phone is using.

Out of the box WAMPServer is designed to be a developer tool and therefore, for security, access to Apache is limited to the single box that is running WAMPServer(Apache). If its not WAMPServer you are running but one of the other WAMP stacks then its basically the same.

Edit your httpd.conf file and change the security config, find this section

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
# Add a line to allow access from your local network(wifi) if thats what you are using 
# to get from the phone to the PC running WAMPServer
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

Note the use of only 3 of the 4 quartiles of the IPV4 network subnet. This will allow any ip in the range 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255 just in case the phone gets a different ip on some other day.

SAVE the httpd.conf file and then restart Apache using the wampmanager icon menus:

```
left click wampmanager->Apache->Service->Restart Service
```

If you are using your phones, mobile data access, then its more of a problem as you will have to port forward your router to allow access to Apache from the outside world, and also add other securty access.

Comment: Error: Unknown Authz provider: 192.168.1 in Wamp 3.2.4.9

Comment: Secondly @OmidOmidi that issue does not sound like its related to this question, do you have a open question somewhere?

Comment: When I edit httpd.conf and restart all services, wampserver does not start. I find that i forget type "ip" after Require, Thanks